# how to pass data from child angular application to parent non-angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular

lets say, I have plain JavaScript parent application which has child angular application ,so how to notify parent application on any data change in child angular application .loading child application in div not in ifrme

Answer (score 0):

You can make a shared js file, in that js file you use something like this
You can use this file either in your plain javascript app or child Angular App

```
var _data = 123;
Object.defineProperty(this, 'yourData', {
  get: function () { return _data; },
  set: function (v) {
    // Changes will be notified here
  }
});
```

// In your child Angular App
// Now you can change the data somewhere

```
print(yourData);
yourData = 456;
print(yourData);
```

Comment: Thanks Tran ,but  I have code access of only child angular application ,this application can be used by any parent application.so when data is saved in child application i need to notify parent application

Answer (score 0):

You could communicate between both using [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

1. Add an event listener in your non-angular application

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  // ... event.data = 'hello there!'
}
```

2. Use window.postMessage() to send data from your angular application

```
window.postMessage("hello there!");
```

Keep in mind to check the event origin, because this event can also be fired from some third-party scripts, iframe or pop-ups

Comment: Thanks Nikolay,i am loading child angular component in div,not using iframe